# How to add my own items in the Delphi Options dialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How do I add my own items to the Delphi Options dialog (Tools\Options)? For example, see the [Project JEDI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/) options.

[image: Screenshot of Project JEDI items in Delphi Options dialog]

For example it is necessary for me that there there was my bookmark with options of compilation for mine a component and new projects.
For example there is at me a new project, in it the panel and on it 3 checkboxes how it there to add?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear. I didn't change the second paragraph, because I can't make head and tails of it. I think you want to add a new Item called "New project" with three checkboxes. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to this are the `INTAEnvironmentOptionsServices` and `INTAAddInOptions` interfaces. Support for add-ins [customising the options dialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tools_API_Changes_for_XE) was added to the Tools API in XE. Your add-in needs to supply an implementation of `INTAAddInOptions`. You register the add-in options by calling `INTAEnvironmentOptionsServices.RegisterAddInOptions`.

If you can't work out how to do this from the Tools API source code then I suggest you download the JCL source code to use as your template.

[Uwe Schuster's blog article](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2010/09/16/xe-ota-1/) on the subject gives a general overview but I can't find any other articles that cover this topic.